# Overriding a block inside Mage/Adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, adminhtml, configuration, overrides

I am trying to override the following block but it isn't working for me

`magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Alerts/Stock.php`

Here's my config file under `app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MF_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MF_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And my module's config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MF_Adminhtml>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MF_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
<catalog_product_edit_tab_alerts_stock>MF_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Alerts_Stock</catalog_product_edit_tab_alerts_stock>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

And the local php class is located under `magento/app/code/local/MF/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Alerts/Stock.php` and looks like this

```
class MF_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Alerts_Stock extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Alerts_Stock
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $websiteId = 0;
        if ($store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getWebsiteId();
        }
        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('MF_ProductAlert')) {
            $collection = Mage::getModel('mf_productalert/stock')
                ->getCustomerCollection()
                ->join($productId, $websiteId);
            $this->setCollection($collection);
        }
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
}
```

Magento is still using the core block instead of the local one. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I cannot spot any mistake. Did you clear the cache? How do you know the block is not used?

Comment: Cleared the cache multiple times. I put a breakpoint on the prepareCollection function on the local block and the core block and the core block is the one being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you call `parent::_prepareCollection();` in your code.

Thus the **original method from the core is being called and thus overrides your changes.**

This is a common mistake when dealing with grid block overrides.

Try to replace that line with `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();` instead

Comment: I've replaced that line but it doesn't even get to the local function to get to the parent call, must be something else.

Comment: @jrmf is your module enabled ? Do you see an corresponding entry in `core_resource` ?

Comment: Nope, problem was that I forgot to add .xml to my file under app/etc/modules